# About how to increase the FIR filter sampling frequency in FPGA? And what is the tradeoff of increasing the sampling frequency?

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response

I am trying to implement a FIR filter on FPGA and trying to have a solid understanding of the FIR filter tap delay and sampling frequency.

Does the “one tap” delay equal to “1/Fs (sampling frequency)”? If I have N-tap, the total delay will be N/Fs? If the Fs sampling frequency is increased, the “one tap” delay is decreased?

Is there any trade off/drawback of increasing the sampling frequency? Maybe it will take more processing time for the output y(n) to come out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does the “one tap” delay equal to “1/Fs (sampling frequency)”?

Yes

> If I have N-tap, the total delay will be N/Fs?

Depends on how you define "total" delay, but in general the answer is no. For a minimum phase filter the delay will be 1. For a linear phase filter it would roughly be N/2

> If the Fs sampling frequency is increased, the “one tap” delay is decreased?

Yes. But it also changes the frequency response of your filter.

> Is there any trade off/drawback of increasing the sampling frequency?

Many. It really depends on what the requirements of your application are.

Comment: Hello, Sir. Thank you very much for the reply. For the last question “what is the trade-off/drawback of increasing the sampling frequency”, maybe can you give me a couple potential trade-off/drawback? The only one that I can think of now is that “in FPGA implementation, the z delay is using a D flip flop, and higher Fs will mean that the D flip flop needs be have a shorter “D to Q delay (shorter delay is a little more challenging for hardware). Thank you.